# Hub method from client is not invoking in ASP.NET Core SignalR

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr.client, asp.net-core-signalr

I'm adding SignalR to my app. I can send messages from server to client, but can't call hub methods from client. Here's my hub interface:

```
public interface IGeneralHub
{
    Task BroadcastMessage(HubMessage msg); //string type, string payload);
    Task JoinHub(List<int> ids);
}
```

and hub client:

```
public class AuctionHub : Hub<IGeneralHub>
{
    public void Broadcast(HubMessage msg)
    {
        Clients.All.BroadcastMessage(msg);
    }
    public void JoinHub(List<int> ids)
    {
        foreach (var id in ids.Distinct())
            Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, id.ToString());
    }
}
```

And client side:

```
this.hubConnections = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
                    .withUrl(`${environment.hubHost}/document/`)
                    .build();

this.hubConnections.start()
                    .then(() => console.log('Connection started'))
                    .catch(err => console.log('Error while starting connection: ' + err));

this.hubConnections.invoke('joinGroup', JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('ws-document')));
```

I receive messages, but `joinGroup` is never called. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

> I receive messages, but joinGroup is never called. What am I doing wrong?

This is because there is no `JoinGroup` method in your `AuctionHub` class. It should `JoinHub` instead as follows:

```
this.hubConnections.invoke('joinHub', JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('ws-document')));
```

Comment: true. i changed method's name and put a breakpoint there, but it still isn't called. also, for some reason after user connects to hub application freezes and does not send any responses, all request from client side are marked as pending

Comment: @Jamil There is some configuration problem surely! Can you give remote access with team viewer please!

Comment: @Jamil question is how are you calling this line `this.hubConnections.invoke('joinGroup', JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('ws-document')));`

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but I don't think that's possible( What's wrong with that line? This method should add user to groups, group names are IDs, which are stored in localStorage['ws-document']

Comment: Okay! but you have to invoke this method with something like on button click event etc. otherwise how will it being called?

Comment: It should be called once, after user connects to hub.

Comment: That means when your document is ready this will called automatically? Moreover add your full client side code inside script tag to the question.

Comment: No, after authorization user receives a list of document IDs that are related to him, he connects to hub and calls that method once, I need it only after initial connection.
That's almost all client code, I removed on('BroadcastMessage') and hubConnection declaration

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188204/discussion-between-tanvirarjel-and-jamil).